# Tapping RR Twice doesn't hot reload/refresh the React native android app

Tags: android, react-native

Tapping RR twice doesn't load the latest changes (js file changed) on to simulator. I am using API 23, Nexus 6 android simulator. Did anyone else facing this issue. Any solution?  I am using MAC

I am new to react native. 
Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do cmd+m and cmd+r give you? (Or ctrl in case you are on windows). I remember having a similar issue with the use of Genymotion, so I refreshed with cmd+r or the menu popping up with cmd+m.

Comment: is `live reload` or `hot reloading` enables on your device ?

Comment: @stephanmantel cmd+m will give the option about Reload, Debug JS Remotely and other options..

Comment: If someone downvote the question, please mention the reason to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 'watching' the file changes to update your simulator once you have made js changes?Add a hot reloading or a watcher to see your changes and for simulator to auto update

Comment: I could see the changes, once I save the files. But I dont want to do that. I want to refresh the app only when I tap on some commands. Moreover, i want t know why RR command not working.